# Updates and Inserts can cause index fragmentation even if you rollback the transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am aware that, some causes for index fragmentation are:

Non Sequential inserts – when doing a non-sequential insert, SQL Server moves ~50% of data from the old page to the newly allocated page. This would result in a page split, with each page having ~50% of data from the old page.

Updates to an existing row value with a larger value, which doesn’t fit on the same page

I have heard that even if you rollback the transaction, the fragmentation remains, but I could not find documentation for that.

does anybody have documentation for that, or a script to prove this?

Comment: What have you tried? Put together a table with an index. Use a guid as the clustered index to make fragmentation easy. Add about 5k rows, check the fragmentation. Then do your insert and rollback, check the fragmentation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I did some tests, and the results were not exactly what I would expect.

The environment:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

First of all I looked for a table that already has fragmentation.
Surprisingly, inside my DBA database I found a table called tableSizeBenchmark.

```
USE [DBA]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableSizeBenchmark](
[lngID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[dbName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[tableName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[creationDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[numberOfRows] [bigint] NULL,
[spaceUsedMb] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tableSizeBenchmark] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[lngID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
  ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
USE [DBA]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIXtableSizeBenchmark] ON [dbo].[tableSizeBenchmark] 
(
[dbName] ASC,
[tableName] ASC,
[creationDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the level of fragmentation BEFORE doing any test:

[image]

You need to create these 2 procedures in order to carry on the same test.
basically I used random string generator and a random number generator, just because I wanted to insert 10,000 records and see how the make the fragmentation worse, and later on ROLLBACK the transaction and see the true, if the fragmentation remains or goes away.

```
--DROP PROCEDURE GetRandomString
--GO
--DROP PROCEDURE GetRandomNumber
--GO
create procedure GetRandomString (@STR VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT)
as
begin

-- generates a random string
-- marcelo miorelli
-- 01-oct-2014

-- one of the other features that makes this more flexible:
-- By repeating blocks of characters in @CharPool, 
-- you can increase the weighting on certain characters so that they are more likely to be chosen.

DECLARE @z INT
      , @i INT
      , @MIN_LENGTH INT
      , @MAX_LENGTH INT


DECLARE @CharPool VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @RandomString VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PoolLength INT

SELECT @MIN_LENGTH = 20
SELECT @MAX_LENGTH = 100

--SET @z = RAND() * (@max_length - @min_length + 1) + @min_length
SET @Z = 50
-- define allowable character explicitly - easy to read this way an easy to 
-- omit easily confused chars like l (ell) and 1 (one) or 0 (zero) and O (oh)
SET @CharPool = 
    'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789.,-_!$@#%^&*'

SET @CharPool = 
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
SET @PoolLength = Len(@CharPool)

SET @i = 0
SET @RandomString = ''

WHILE (@i < @z) BEGIN
    SELECT @RandomString = @RandomString + 
        SUBSTRING(@Charpool, CONVERT(int, RAND() * @PoolLength), 1)
    SELECT @i = @i + 1
END


SELECT @STR = @RandomString

end
GO

create procedure GetRandomNumber (@number int OUTPUT)
as
begin


-- generate random numbers
-- marcelo miorelli
-- 01-oct-2014

DECLARE @maxval INT, @minval INT
select @maxval=10000,@minval=500

SELECT @Number = CAST(((@maxval + 1) - @minval) *
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + @minval AS INT)


end 
go
```

After you have created the procedures above, see below the code that I have used to run this test:

```
SELECT object_id AS ObjectID,
  object_NAME (Object_id) as Table_NAME,
  index_id AS IndexID,
  avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS PercentFragment,
  fragment_count AS TotalFrags,
  avg_fragment_size_in_pages AS PagesPerFrag,
  page_count AS NumPages

FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('dba'),
  NULL, NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('tableSizeBenchmark')
and avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
```

so the result:
After running the above script but BEFORE ROLLBACK OR COMMIT, the transaction is still open:

[image]

Please note that the fragmentation has INCREASED.
Would this fragmentation REMAIN or DISAPPEAR after we rollback this transaction?

Let me post here also, the script that I use to see the fragmentation level:

```
SELECT object_id AS ObjectID,
  object_NAME (Object_id) as Table_NAME,
  index_id AS IndexID,
  avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS PercentFragment,
  fragment_count AS TotalFrags,
  avg_fragment_size_in_pages AS PagesPerFrag,
  page_count AS NumPages

FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('dba'),
  NULL, NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('tableSizeBenchmark')
and avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
```

and the results of this experiment:

[image]

As you can see, the fragmentation levels went back to the original situation, before the transaction.

Hope this helps

Marcelo